# mysql search with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql

Need a bit of help writing query as I have database containing 1000's records of records.

Basically I have a database that contains the following fields

entryID

date

toothNumber

procedureName

studentName

tutorName

isolationSkill

isolationKnowledge

cavitySkill

cavityKnowledge

matrixSkill

matrixKnowledge

restorativeSkill

restorativeKnowledge

I want to write a query that searches all the records for a particular name(for example "Joe Bloggs")  and the procedureName contains "Class II"

On top of that I want it to return the amount of times the Values N, B and C appear in the isolationskill - restorativeKnowldge columns.

So in the end I can see a list like this

Hope this is making sense. Let me know if you require any more information.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There isn't any code, you haven't told us which values are N,B or C. Do you have a query???

Comment: When you say "I have a database that contains the following fields" do you mean that you have a *table* in your database that contains these fields or are they in different tables (from the look of it they do look like they are in a single table, just making sure).

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would give you what you want, without you posting what you would like to see, kinda hard to tell, but this will pop out all the rows just like normal, and then give you a count field for each of the given Value n, B, C fields. Apply this syntax multiple times to get the exact results you are looking for on the different fields.

```
SELECT 
entryID, 
date, 
procedurename, 
studentName, 
tutorName, 
restorativeSkill, 
isolationKnowledge, 
cavitySkill, 
cavityKnowledge, 
matrixSkill, 
matrixKnowledge,
restorativeknowledge,
SUM(IF(isolationSkill = 'N', 1,0)), 
SUM(IF(restorativeKnowldge = 'B', 1,0)) FROM records 
WHERE procedureName = 'Class II' and Name = "Joe Bloggs";
```